# List data filter not showing and not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a list element search. I get the list from the Internet. The data is all displayed, but when I want to use the `_runFilter` method, the data disappears and nothing happens. **1.** How to make data search work? **2.** When I open the page, my _foundAddressesInStationList is empty, but I initialize it and the data should be displayed, why is it not displayed?
Thanks in advance.

```
  List<PublicChargingStationModel> stationsList = [];

  List<PublicChargingStationModel> _foundAddressesInStationList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadStations();
    _foundAddressesInStationList = stationsList;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<PublicChargingStationModel> resultAddressesInStationList = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      resultAddressesInStationList = stationsList;
    } else {
      resultAddressesInStationList = stationsList
          .where((element) => element.address!
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }
    setState(
      () {
        _foundAddressesInStationList = resultAddressesInStationList;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double paddingTop = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: _child(size, paddingTop),
    );
  } 

  void _loadStations() async {
    final StationCubit stationCubit = BlocProvider.of<StationCubit>(context);

    stationsList = await stationCubit.getPublicChargingStation();
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw you used the Cubit, can you please add your full code of cubit and its states?

Comment: Updated the code, but I don't use cubit much in this case. The data comes to me, I checked it, but the filter does not work and when opened, they also do not display, when they enter some value in the text field, then all the data will be shown but not filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the init method you are calling your cubit which is asynchronous, but without waiting for the result you initialize the _foundAddressesInStationList with stationList which is empty. So, initialize the _foundAddressesInStationList in the load method like this.

```
  void _loadStations() async {
    final StationCubit stationCubit = BlocProvider.of<StationCubit>(context);
    stationsList = await stationCubit.getPublicChargingStation();
    _foundAddressesInStationList = stationsList;
    setState((){});
  }
```

2. Filter should work fine. Do you have any warnings or errors? Do you have expected values in resultAddressesInStationList while filtering?

Edit:
Alternate Approach for Filter:

```
stationsList.forEach((element) { 
    if(element.address!.toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase())) {
      resultAddressesInStationList.add(element);
    }
  });
_foundAddressesInStationList = resultAddressesInStationList;
setState(() {});
```

The only place you added null check operator is element.address!. "Null check operator used on a null value" means the address should be null or should not exists.

Also try element["address"]

Edit 2:

You Search Widget like this should be:

```
class MySearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MySearchWidget(
      {Key? key,
        required this.onChanged, this.isListClear})
      : super(key: key);

  final Function(String?) onChanged;
  final Function(bool)? isListClear;

  @override
  State<MySearchWidget> createState() => _MySearchWidget();
}

class _MySearchWidget extends State<MySearchWidget> {
  late FocusNode myFocusNode;
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onBackPressed(context) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
          onPressed: () {
            _onBackPressed(context);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 14),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _textController,
              focusNode: myFocusNode,
              autofocus: true,
              onChanged: (value) => widget.onChanged(value),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: _textController.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _textController.clear();
                    widget.isListClear!(true);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  ),
                )
                    : const SizedBox(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If not used like this, the change method of this widget will be called while initializing the widget and it will filter your data for the empty string which is unwanted and will also raise issues.

But the actual error is the null operator. I guess your PublicChargingStationModel class should have the 'address' property as not null.

So you should not use like

```
resultAddressesInStationList = stationsList
    .where((element) => element.address!
    .toLowerCase()
    .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
    .toList();
```

instead, use it like

```
resultAddressesInStationList = stationsList
    .where((element) => element.address
    .toLowerCase()
    .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
    .toList();
```

or change your model address property to nullable and keep your filter as it is now.

```
class PublicChargingStationModel{
  final String? address;

  PublicChargingStationModel({required this.address});
}
```

Comment: Yes, now the data is displayed. But the filter doesn't work. When I enter characters into a text field, I get Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: If possible add a screenshot. By having breakpoint. From a coding perspective, it seems legit. Also add the model class.

Comment: When I enter characters in a text field, when I enter one character, this error appears https://i.stack.imgur.com/W936B.jpg

Comment: Maybe because I'm using a List<PublicChargingStationModel> and I need to use index to iterate over the elements?

Comment: That should not be the case. Edited the answer check and find the error.

Comment: It's still a problem. Even when entering characters, suffixIcon does not appear in the text field for me, although it should appear if text is entered. You can see I updated the code and added the Search Widget, maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Here is an error when entering characters in a text field https://i.stack.imgur.com/v859I.jpg